# Custom a touchable text like See more

Tags: performance, reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight

I am writing a react native app. 
I want to make a press. See more like we usually see for more information of something. How can I do that?

[Like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP0IG.png)

Comment: Please read this an edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` components have an `onPress` prop, where you can pass an **arrow function**

```
<Text onPress = {() => this.myFunction()}>
    See More
</Text>
```

Note: Adding some style props, eg `color: 'blue'` and `fontWeight: 600` can help your text look pretty similar to your provided photo.

Comment: thks u for your helping